# How can I simplify this Jquery code?

Tags: jquery, function, simplify

```
$('a#golf-link').click(function () {
    $('ul#golf').fadeIn(500);
    $('ul.img-list').not('#golf').fadeOut(200);
    $('a#golf-link').addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not('#golf-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
$('a#bags-link').click(function () {
    $('ul#bags').fadeIn(500);
    $('ul.img-list').not('#bags').fadeOut(200);
    $('a#bags-link').addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not('#bags-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
$('a#keyrings-link').click(function () {
    $('ul#keyrings').fadeIn(500);
    $('ul.img-list').not('#keyrings').fadeOut(200);
    $('a#keyrings-link').addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not('#keyrings-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
```

As you can see, the code above is repetitive and I would like to simplify it.

I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminologies here but you should get the gist of it.

What I'd like to do is create a function like so

```
$('a#l-//VARIABLE-HERE//-link').click(function () {
    $('div#l-//VARIABLE-HERE//').fadeIn(500);
    $('div.clothes-type').not('#l-//VARIABLE-HERE//').fadeOut(200);
    $('a#l-//VARIABLE-HERE//-link').addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not('#l-//VARIABLE-HERE//-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
```

and all I'll need to do call the function and replace //VARIABLE-HERE// with things like golf, bags, keyrings etc etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the code already work, and you want to improve its quality? Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Show us your actual HTML and you'll get even more compact options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your naming convention will be constant:

```
function setItUp(objName) {
    $('a#' + objName + '-link').click(function() {
    $('ul#' + objName).fadeIn(500);
        $('ul.img-list').not('#' + objName).fadeOut(200);
        $('a#' + objName + '-link').addClass("current-link");
        $('.side-menu li a').not('#' + objName + '-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
}
```

Then make your calls:

```
setItUp('golf');
setItUp('bags');
setItUp('keyrings');
```

Answer (score 3):

The most simplified it could be would be by using common classes among all three sets of objects so that the identical code could work everywhere.  We'd have to see the actual HTML to know how to recommend that more specifically though.

Next most, you could make a single function that takes one parameter that sets up the click handler and carries out the click action.

```
function configureClick(item) {
    $('a' + item + '-link').click(function() {
        $('ul' + item).fadeIn(500);
        $('ul.img-list').not(item).fadeOut(200);
        $('a' + item + '-link').addClass("current-link");
        $('.side-menu li a').not(item + '-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
}

configureClick("#golf");
configureClick("#bags");
configureClick("#keyrings");
```

Then lastly, if you show us the actual HTML, there may be a geometric arrangement between the various items that combined with tags and identifiers that could be coded to identify which ones to work on for a given click (parents, siblings, tag types, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$('a[id$="-link"]').click(function () {

    itemName =  $(this).attr('id').replace("-link","");

    $('div#'+itemName).fadeIn(500);
    $('div.clothes-type').not('#l-'+itemName).fadeOut(200);
    $('a#l-'+itemName +'-link').addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not('#l-'+itemName +'-link').removeClass("current-link");        

});
```

Answer (score 0):

User this

```
$('a#golf-link,a#bags-link,a#keyrings-link').click(function () {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var currentType = currentId.replace("-link", "");

    $('ul#'+currentType).fadeIn(500);
    $('ul.img-list').not('#'+currentType).fadeOut(200);
    $('a#'+currentId).addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not('#'+currentId).removeClass("current-link");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[id$="-link"]').click(function () {
    var idVal = "#" + this.id.match(/(.*)-link/)[1]
    $('ul'+idVal).fadeIn(500);
    $('ul.img-list').not(idVal).fadeOut(200);
    $('a'+idVal+'-link').addClass("current-link");
    $('.side-menu li a').not(idVal+'-link').removeClass("current-link");
    });
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
$(menu).click(function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id.split('-')[0],
        clss = 'current-link';

    $(e.target).closest('li').addClass(clss).siblings().removeClass(clss);
    $('#' + id, imgslist).fadeIn(500).siblings(':visible').fadeOut(200);
});
```

where `menu` is the `.side-menu` element, and `imglist` is the `.img-list` element. I recommend you to define those references on page load / DOM ready like so:

```
var menu = $('.side-menu')[0],
    imglist = $('.img-list')[0];
```

(of course, do this only if those elements are static on the page)

Btw, I've defined that the class is set on the LI element rather than the ANCHOR element, because it makes the JavaScript code simpler and more readable (and it's also a good practice in CSS to define the class on the outermost element that represents an entity).